# Android: get route of file

Tags: android

I need the route of a pdf file in my Android Project.

The file could be in raw or in assets folder.

I need to get the route because I must call using the File Class

Ex:  File file = new File(path);

Thanks

Image:

http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/2303/capturaww.png

Comment: Here are [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: The file is inside my Android project

Comment: Yes, i need i path of pdf file because I must send this file by email. I can send mail with files, but i can't get the path of pdf file

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you mean, assuming you want to read to PDF file in your assets (res file) look here

- [Access PDF files from 'res/raw' or assets folder programmatically to parse with given methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020299/access-pdf-files-from-res-raw-or-assets-folder-programmatically-to-parse-with)

But if you want to get the file path of a folder, then look here

- [how to get file path from sd card in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858107/how-to-get-file-path-from-sd-card-in-android)
- [How to get the file path from URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885204/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-uri)

Here is an example of how to get a file path (taken from the third link)

```
File myFile = new File(uri.toString());

myFile.getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: It's easy understand, i need the path of pdf file which is inside of my Android proyect in folder raw or assets

Comment: It's impossible doing this.

I solve this problem copying file from assets to sdcard, and them creating File object. Thanks